# Access created file C#

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application where on a button click, a program is run that creates a file. I want to output the contents of that (txt) file into a textbox. I can see when debugging the file is created, but I get a File not found error. If I click continue, it then works.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fp = EscapeArguments(filepath);

    string strCmdText = "some command";

    Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);

    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fp);
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fp);

    string txtfp = dir + "\\" + name +  + ".txt";

    string txtout;
    if (File.Exists(txtfp))
    {
        txtout= File.ReadAllText(txtfp);
        textBox1.Text = txtout;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is txtfp1? Do you mean txtfp?

Comment: You're checking if `txtfp1` exists but then reading from `txtfp`...

Comment: While you're at it, look into [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.1) instead that error prone string concatenation. `.. + name + + ".txt";`is gut wrenching.

Comment: that was just a typo sorry, there's only one txtfp, I've edited it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the process hasn't finished creating the file by the time your application is looking for it. Try waiting for the process to exit before continuing:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: thanks, that works! I was adding await Task.Delay(200), this is a more proper solution.